# it&#039;s instead of it's in python string

Tags: python, string, single-quotes

My python string consists of `&#039;` instead of ' (single quotes). My current objective is to expand compound words like It's to It is, Haven't to Have not.

> "This has been great for me. I&#039;ve been on it for 2 weeks and in the last week I only had 3 headaches which went away with 2 Tylenol. I was having chronic daily headaches that wouldn&#039;t go away no matter what I took. I&#039;m still a little sleepy during the day, but I know that will get better."

The above statement is an example of the sentence I've been trying to convert.

Can someone suggest a way to convert this into the string format?

Comment: Are you using python2? If so switch to python3 and then look at unicode handling.

Comment: @match I am using Python3 only.

Comment: This has nothing to do with unicode, those are merely HTML entities, @match. That piece of text is HTML-encoded. HTML-decode it.

Comment: html module? https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html

Comment: Ugh - you're completely right - too early, need coffee!

Comment: @deceze Make an answer for this comment. I had the same problem, when used html.unescape() it solved it

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
text = "This has been great for me. I&#039;ve been on it for 2 weeks and in the last week I only had 3 headaches which went away with 2 Tylenol. I was having chronic daily headaches that wouldn&#039;t go away no matter what I took. I&#039;m still a little sleepy during the day, but I know that will get better."
d_contraction = {"I'm":"I am","wouldn't":"would not","I've":"I have"}
updated_text = text.replace('&#039;', "'") 
print(updated_text)
for k,v in d_contraction.items():
    updated_text = updated_text.replace(k,v) 
print(updated_text)
```

Output:

```
This has been great for me. I've been on it for 2 weeks and in the last week I only had 3 headaches which went away with 2 Tylenol. I was having chronic daily headaches that wouldn't go away no matter what I took. I'm still a little sleepy during the day, but I know that will get better.

This has been great for me. I have been on it for 2 weeks and in the last week I only had 3 headaches which went away with 2 Tylenol. I was having chronic daily headaches that would not go away no matter what I took. I am still a little sleepy during the day, but I know that will get better.
```

The above code will work for the text you have provided. Basically, you will have to create a dictionary of all the possible contractions examples - they'll, ther're, etc.

Comment: This is malpractice, when you have such problem, you should find the root of the problem and deal with it. Not solving each separately, because this problem may reappear in different format.